# Emitting states from a bloc using bloc.emit

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm building a phone authentication ui (OTP) using `firebase_auth` library with BLoC pattern (a bit of an overkill for this ui, but the whole project is in BLoC, so). I'm processing the authentication within the BLoC, as such:

```
  @override
  Stream<PhoneAuthState> mapEventToState(PhoneAuthEvent event) async* {
    ....
    else if(event is PhoneNumberSubmittedEvent) yield* _handlePhoneNumberSubmittedEvent(event);
    ....
  }

  Stream<PhoneAuthState> _handlePhoneNumberSubmittedEvent(PhoneNumberSubmittedEvent event) async*{
      yield SendingCodeState();

      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      var firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

      await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: _buildPhoneNumber(),
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 0),
        verificationCompleted: (firebaseUser) {},
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},


        // Relevant code

        codeSent: (id, [forceResendingToken]) =>
          emit(_codeSentState(id, forceResendingToken)),

        verificationFailed: (error) =>
          emit(_verificationFailedState(error)),
      );
  }
```

Because the results of my `_codeSentState` and `_verificationFailedState` functions cannot be yielded from within the `handlePhoneNumberSubmittedEvent` method, I used `emit` (which is actually working fine).

However, as I was looking through BLoC docs, I found that `emit` is `@protected`, and the docs stating:

> [emit] should never be used outside of tests.

So I have three questions:

1. Why shouldn't `emit` be used outside of tests?
2. Is there an alternative to `emit`? (other than yielding in response to events in `mapEventToState`)
3. Is there a way to `yield` the result of a function that is passed as a parameter to a method/constructor call? (in my case, is there a way to `yield` the results of `_codeSentState` and/or `_verificationFailedState` that are called within `firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber.codeSent` and `firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber.verificationFailed` respectively?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `flutter_bloc` version 8.0.0, this issue was resolved. The method `mapEventToState` was replaced with the more efficient `on<Event>` to respond to events. `on` method provides an `emitter` as a parameter to its callback, which can be used to emit states as needed. In other words, the code I mentioned in OP can now be written as follows

```
// constructor
MyBloc() : super(MyInitialState) {
  on<PhoneNumberSubmittedEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(SendingCodeState());

      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      var firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

      await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: _buildPhoneNumber(),
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 0),
        verificationCompleted: (firebaseUser) {},
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},

        codeSent: (id, [forceResendingToken]) =>
          emit(_codeSentState(id, forceResendingToken)),

        verificationFailed: (error) =>
          emit(_verificationFailedState(error)),
      );
  });
}
```

Comment: That's fine if emit is inside the on<Event>{} but how do I trigger the event outside of that? Like in a different controller where I don't have the context.

I asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72029115/flutter-how-to-trigger-a-bloc-event-in-the-controller

Answer (score 2):

migrate to the new version of the bloc (>=6.0.0) wich bloc is integrated with cubit and the best practice is to bloc class extends the Cubit class and using the emit function to yield new state
read more on the bloc pub page : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

**Update**

as I mentioned in the new version author of the bloc migrated the bloc with the cubit package which adds an alternative and simplified capability to control the state of the application
if your bloc class is extending the bloc base class so you should use (yilding state) pattern for controling the state but if your bloc extends cubit you can directly use the emit method to control the state you can read about it in the documentation here is the link: http://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/packages/bloc/README.md

Comment: I have narrowed down my question to three points, and your answer provides an answer to none of them. It only points at the documentation and explains how `flutter_bloc` is built.

Comment: @Skullz I am saying your question is related to the previous versions of the bloc and in the new version it is not true and u can use the emit  function inside bloc by default and it is not bounded just for using in the tests

Comment: I already have the latest version. If you check their [official documentation](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/packages/bloc/lib/src/bloc.dart), it says `[emit] should never be used outside of tests.` They do expose the method, but only for testing.

Comment: @Skullz as I mentioned  in my answer in the new version author of the bloc migrated the bloc with the cubit package which adds an alternative and simplified capability to control the state of the application if your bloc class is extending bloc base class so you should use (yilding state) pattern for controling the state but if your bloc extends cubit you can directly use the emit method to control the state u can read about it in the documentation here is the link : https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/packages/bloc/README.md